# Constraint on hasMany or callback when addTo or removeFrom is called

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Is there any other generic approach to receving a callback, when an object is added to a `hasMany`-relationship (like `addTo` or `removeFrom` is called)? Unfortunately `beforeValidate` is not called when an object is added or removed or at least the property `hasManyXYs` is not dirty if an object is removed or added. I need to do something, if an object is added or removed from a `ABC`.

```
class ABC {
    List hasManyXYs
    static hasMany = [hasManyXYs: XY]
}
```

I tried to add a constraint to the list:

```
class ABC {
    List hasManyXYs
    static hasMany = [hasManyXYs: XY]

    static constraints = {
        hasManyXYs(validator: {
            true
        }
    }       
}
```

But at least as of grails version 2.0.5, the server does not start and gives an error like this:

```
No such property: hasManyXYs for class: XY
Possible solutions: hasManyXYs. Stacktrace follows:
```

Comment: "No such property: hasManyXYs for class: XY".  That looks like you have code somewhere that is trying to refer to the `hasManyXYs` property on an instance of `XY`, which isn't shown in the description.  "Is there any other generic approach to receving a message, when addTo or removeFrom is called?" I don't understand that question and it isn't clear what that has to do with constraints.

Comment: Thx for your feedback. I updated the question, maybe it is more clear now?

Comment: "No such property: hasManyXYs for class: XY".  Do you have code somewhere which is trying to refer to the `hasManyXYs` property on the `XY` class?  That is what that error message suggests.  I don't know what your `XY` class looks like but presumably it does not have a property named `hasManyXYs`.

Comment: Have a look at the class `ABC` from the question, the list is shown there.

Comment: As I said a couple of times above, the error message suggests that you might have code somewhere which is referring to the `hasManyXYs` property on an instance of `XY` or on the `XY` class itself.  Is that the case?  That is what the error message suggests.

Comment: If you show the stack trace, that will probably clear it up.

Comment: The code in the description has a mistake but I assume that is just a typo in the question and not in your real code.  There is a closing paren ")" missing after your validator closure.

Comment: Aside from the missing paren, the code you have shown above is fine.  The problem has to be somewhere else you haven't shown.  The stack trace will illuminate that.

Comment: Thank you very much, unfortunately I cannot show you the stack trace currently. Will append it tomorrow morning. Thanks in advance.